# Textarea -> php -> mysql -> php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I got this code. I want to update mysql through textarea. I echo my MySQL in textarea, but I don't know how to update it, should I put everyting in something because _GET mode gives me nothing, also I tried to _GET "result" but its same.

```
<fieldset>
    <form method="post" class="jNice">
        <p>
            <textarea>
                <?php
                $result = mysql_query("select html from content where name = 'pagrindinis'");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo $row['html'];
                }
                ?>
            </textarea>
        </p>

        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['keisti'])) {
            $change_info = array
                (
                "html" => mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['html'])
            );

            foreach ($change_info as $info)
                if (empty($info))
                    $klaida = "Tuščias langas";
            if (empty($klaida)) {
                mysql_query("UPDATE `content` SET `html` = '" . $_GET['html'] . "'  where `name` = 'pagrindinis'");
                echo "Informacija atnaujinta";
            } else
                echo $klaida;
        }
        ?>                   
        <input type="submit" value="Keisti" name="keisti">

    </form>

</fieldset>
```

Or maybe you know anything better for website editing? I want to edit websites code in text area, to save space in index.php. I heard something about *richtext* but not much. All anwers would be good.
P.S. Code editing is in admin panel.

Comment: Why is the textarea without a name?

Comment: You really need to read the basics first.

Comment: Your sending a POST, not a GET `<form method="post" class="jNice">`.

Comment: Also, are your shorthand single line loop/conditionals intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put name tag to your textarea input -> **name="html"**

```
 <textarea name="html">
    <?php  
    $result = mysql_query("select html from content where name = 'pagrindinis'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       echo $row['html'];
    }
    ?>
 </textarea>
```